# SSH automate ftp upload

Tags: ftp, ssh

I have a website that I work on locally and is hosted with a web host on another server. How would I use SSH to automatically push my local files to the production server? Would it possible to setup a list of files that are on my local machine that I do not want uploaded and can I have it upload only the files that have changes?

**EDIT**: Thanks for the replies, I actually just started using git today so I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Rob Di Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24195/rob-di-marco) mentions, [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) is a great way to copy your files.  Another option I've recently switched to is using [git](http://git-scm.com/) for this purpose, which also works over ssh and gives us version control.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) would be a great tool for you to use.  It can run over SSH and can figure out what has changed.  You can tell it to ignore files as well.

Comment: +1 I used to user rsync for disaster recovery back in the day.  It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

I would use scp.

You could write a simple script to stage your upload files to certain directory (that way you exclude the other files), then push them to you server that way.

[I use ssh and cvs.](http://cvs.ecoinformatics.org/HOWTO-cvs-over-ssh.html) (the basic idea is there, just ignore the university specific stuff)

I check in my code on a regular basis, then I label it. On the webserver, I check out the latest label. It makes backing out super easy and updating super easy as well.

Then I never have to worry about files getting there that I don't want and because it is tunned via SSH it is totally secure.

Both the webserver and cvs server are linux boxes which really simplifies things.

Take a look at [WinSCP](http://winscp.net) as well.